# Image intervention adding black noise to the background when saving a PNG as JPG

Tags: laravel, intervention

I'm currently using [intervention/image](https://packagist.org/packages/intervention/image) to resize images and save them as JPG.

I have the same code running locally in Windows and remotely in Ubuntu 20.20.

In Windows it does the conversion PNG to JPG converting the transparent background into white. However, in Ubuntu, is adding black noise on top of the white background.

The code I run is:

```php
$resize = Image::make($img)->encode('jpg');
$resize->height() > $resize->width() ? $width = null : $height = null;
$resize->resize($width, $height, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
});
```

Should I add something else before the `encode` in order to ensure that the transparency makes white?

[image]

Comment: On macOS I get white background using your code https://i.imgur.com/HcZwN3Q.jpg , by black noise...do you mean the black borders around the objects?

Comment: Thanks @SalimDjerbouh, I mean this https://i.imgur.com/W3AfS27.png

Comment: @InigoEC What image library are you using?

Comment: Currently intervention/image support both gd and imagick.

Comment: Try installing these optimization tools `sudo apt install jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle -y && npm install -g svgo`

Comment: @loic.lopez I tried both, but none of them work

Comment: @SalimDjerbouh do I need to update any configuration to make them work?

Comment: I have the same problem with ubuntu 20... did you solve?

Comment: I gave up and started saving it as PNG - I then display it in a white background anyway